# Xamarin Forms differences between Android label and UWP

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.android, label

This screenshot is the result of UWP as Startup Project. It is exactly what I want.
!https://1drv.ms/u/s!An07nml8jWWSwbUM-Y5E7IFVZYlb1A
This screenshot is the result of Android as Startup Project. It is not what I want. The labels don't display the text completely, they do not display all of the fields, and only one image appears which is not the correct one. 
!https://1drv.ms/u/s!An07nml8jWWSwbUOmo4tPelZlxknYA

Why such radical differences between the two projects? I know that there are some minor differences but this is too much and not useable. Where do I start to learn how to make the Android version work?

```
using OFam.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace OFam.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainView : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Models.TreeBranches> branches { get; set; }
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            branches = new ObservableCollection<Models.TreeBranches>();
            ListView viewList = new ListView();
            this.Title = "Family Tree";
            viewList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomTreeBranches));
            branches.Add(new Models.TreeBranches {
                BranchNumber = 1,
                FullName = "Garland Don Osborne",
                Birthday ="1/22/1922",
                Father = "Dick Osborn",
                Mother = "Hazel Hinton",
                Spouse1 = "Iola May Hayes",
                Spouse2 = "",
                Spouse3 = "",
                Child1 = "John Richard Osborne",
                Child2 = "Donna May Osborne",
                Child3 = "Garland Darrell Osborne",
                Child4 = "Orval Ray Osborne",
                Residence = "Oakdale, California",
                Image = "Photos/GarlandDonOsborne.jpg" });
            branches.Add(new Models.TreeBranches {
                BranchNumber = 2,
                FullName = "Iola May Hayes",
                Birthday ="11/31/1920",
                Father = "Raymond Hayes",
                Mother = "Gracie Postoak",
                Spouse1 = "Garland Don Osborne",
                Spouse2 = "",
                Spouse3 = "",
                Child1 = "John Richard Osborne",
                Child2 = "Donna May Osborne",
                Child3 = "Garland Darrell Osborne",
                Child4 = "Orval Ray Osborne",
                Residence = "Highlands Ranch, Colorado",
                Image = "Photos/IolaMayHayes.jpg" });
public class CustomTreeBranches : ViewCell 
            {
            public CustomTreeBranches()
            {
                var img = new Image();
                var bdLabel = new Label();
                var nameLabel = new Label();
                var bnLabel = new Label();
                var frLabel = new Label();
                var mrLabel = new Label();
                var c1Label = new Label();
                var c2Label = new Label();
                var c3Label = new Label();
                var c4Label = new Label();
                var s1Label = new Label();
                var s2Label = new Label();
                var s3Label = new Label();
                var rdLabel = new Label();
                    var sp1Label = new Label()
                {
                    Text = "Father and Mother",
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                };
                var sp2Label = new Label()
                {
                    Text = "Children",
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                }; 
                var sp3Label = new Label()
                {
                    Text = "Spouse(s)",
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                }; 
                var sp4Label = new Label()
                {
                    Text = "Latest Residence",
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                }; 
                var vLayout = new StackLayout();
                var hLayout = new StackLayout() { BackgroundColor = Color.LavenderBlush };
                img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Image"));
                bdLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Birthday"));
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("FullName"));                
                frLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Father"));
                mrLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Mother"));
                c1Label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Child1"));
                c2Label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Child2"));
                c3Label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Child3"));
                c4Label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Child4"));
                s1Label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Spouse1"));
                s2Label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Spouse2"));
                s3Label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Spouse3"));
                rdLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Residence"));
                hLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
                hLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
                img.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
                img.WidthRequest = 250;
                img.HeightRequest = 250;
                nameLabel.FontSize = 18;
                vLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
                vLayout.Children.Add(nameLabel);
                vLayout.Children.Add(bdLabel);
                vLayout.Children.Add(sp1Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(frLabel);
                vLayout.Children.Add(mrLabel);
                vLayout.Children.Add(sp2Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(c1Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(c2Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(c3Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(c4Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(sp3Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(s1Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(s2Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(s3Label);            
                vLayout.Children.Add(sp4Label);
                vLayout.Children.Add(rdLabel);
                hLayout.Children.Add(vLayout);
                hLayout.Children.Add(img);
                View = hLayout;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the Label - on Android it appears that is needs a hint to correctly calculate the height of each row in the ListView.  Try setting a HeightRequest value on your ViewCell.  I'd also suggest starting with a simpler layout and gradually adding content to it, rather than add in all of your content at once and trying to debug it.

Comment: I don't know about `UWP` specifically, but I can say that the `ListView` has a default fixed `Height` of 40dpi for its cells. Try just set the `HasUnevenRows` property on your ListView's declaring to `True`. It'll make each cell render with the size needed for its content.